# Having a trouble with Asynchronous image loading in ListView

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, android-arrayadapter

this is very big trouble for me, I have been working for hours on this, and no clue !

I having a problem with Asynchronous image loading in ListView.

I'm using Parse.com as my application's Backend, i'm retrieving Messages and their images from the Parse.com class.

Everything is working fine, when I scroll Up/Down, or Load the list view again, the Pictures Mixed, and all pictures Reload in another order, and after few seconds they will ordered as I want, but this is a big issue for me.

I think this is happening because I'm using class like this to Upload images

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
```

Anyway my adapter class is the following :

```
public class adapterview extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {
Bitmap image;
public adapterview(Context context, ArrayList<Message> Messages) {
   super(context, 0, Messages);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // Get the data item for this position
   final Message m = getItem(position);    
   // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom2, parent, false);
   }

   TextView message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
   TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
   TextView user = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user);
   message.setText(m.getMessage());
   user.setText(m.getUser()); 
   new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
   .execute(m.getImage());

   return convertView;


}


 private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
  ImageView bmImage;

  public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
      this.bmImage = bmImage;
  }

  protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String urldisplay = urls[0];
      Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
      try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return mIcon11;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
      bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
  }
}
```

and this is my message class :

```
public class Message {

String message;
String user;
String phone;
String image;
String date;

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

and this how i'm adding items to my list :

```
contacts c = new contacts();
            c.setName(object.get("name").toString());
            c.setNumero(object.get("phone").toString());
            ParseFile image = (ParseFile)object.get("Profil");
            c.setProfil(image.getUrl());
            messagelist.addcontact(c);
```

and this is the code how i'm filling the list view from the MainActivity :

```
        adapterview adapter = new adapterview(MainActivity.this, (ArrayList<Message>) messagelist);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is two screenshots when I scroll Down and then Up so the picture of the first listItem changes !! for no reason and then get back to the normal picture after some seconds.

[image]

[image]

If you can suggest a new way on how I can upload the images from URL to ImageView, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are observing is i think due to the viewholder pattern of the listview.You are trying to download and set image to the images via aysnctask in getview() but when you scrollup or down the view get recycled and when you again go to that position your getview called for that position so the asynctask is again executed and it download the set the image in imageview again therefore you see the delay,i would suggest you to use **PICASSO**  libraray from square it is quite efficient for image downloads and caches your images also here is the link http://square.github.io/picasso/ or use **Glide** which is now officially recommended by Google,here is the github link [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: @NadadorBase Base happy to help

Answer (score 1):

last time I also used manual downloading avatars of contacts, but it's bad.
Your problem I think:

- Download avatar, then set to ImageView
- But, you are using ViewHolder pattern, so new downloaded avatar will set to many imageview > wrong avatar for specified contact (This only run well when all avatars are downloaded)

First, check Universal Image Loader library, set avatar URL to the view and it will automatically download, cache your avatars into memory.

Then post here if you still get wrong avatar problem.

Comment: Can you please give more details on how can I do what you have said ?? can you give a tutorial, and any source

Answer (score 1):

> the Pictures Mixed, and all pictures Reload in another order, and
>   after few seconds they will ordered as I want

This weird behavior happening due to `AsyncTask` in `getView` method without **View Holder Pattern**.

To avoid rendering already rendered thumbnail images again and load new images from network in listview on scroll use View Holder pattern.

See following useful tutorial for creating ListView with good scroll and loading performace using View Holder:

[Performance Tips for Android’s ListView](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/)

Answer (score 1):

That happens because ListView recycle the views when you scroll, and then when you call your async task for downloading of the pictures and scroll, the download finish but the reference points to a recycled view and one or more async task pointing to the same view. One way you could avoid this its tagging you view when a download start, and when the download end, before you draw the image check if its the actual reference the correct and then draw the image.

You could tag the view with the URL of the image because its a unique value.

In the preExecute of the download you must tag the ImageView with the URL(String).

```
imageView.setTag(url);
```

And when the task finish and before draw the image, recover the tag and check it.

```
String tag = (String)imageView.getTag();
if(tag != null && tag.equals(url)){
    //Draw the image
} else {
    //Draw the placeholder or clean the ImageView
}
```

And you can upgrade the performance of you ListView using the ViewHolder pattern, and why you download the image manually when Parse can perform it by their API, for the Parse way and using a Cache policy, when you download a image automatically cached the bitmap, and when you ask again for the download just retrieved the cached result.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I solved by using Recycle view's `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    CartsViewModel currentData = data.get(i);
    ParseFile image = currentData.getParseImage();
    if(image!=null){
        Log.d(TAG,"image not null. Downloading....");
        image.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                if(e==null){
                    Log.d(TAG,"donload finished");
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    viewHolder.cartImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                }else{
                    viewHolder.cartImage.setImageBitmap(null);
                }
            }else{
                viewHolder.cartImage.setImageBitmap(null);
            }
        });
    }
    viewHolder.cartName.setText(currentData.getCartName());
    viewHolder.cartAddress.setText(currentData.getCartAddress());
    viewHolder.rating.setText(currentData.getRating());
    viewHolder.reviewCount.setText(currentData.getReviewCount());

}
```

works like charm with the parse method.

Comment: I'm solved calling `viewHolder.cartImage.setImageBitmap(null);` before load

Answer (score 0):

What is the listview cell layout xml file?
I think the Android can't determine the cell size of listview. This causes some issues.
If you want to use async loading images, one way to escape the issue is to fix the image size. For example

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_icon1"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    />
```